# Counting all substring cases in a string

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I am counting the occurrence of specific keypairs in a word

```
console.log("acceptable".match(/ab|ac|ar/gi).length); //2
```

[(picture) Example of just keypairs on regex101.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8GNsB.png)

This works as expected, but including anchored single letters, like "^a" overwrites other matches:

```
console.log("acceptable".match(/^a|ab|ac|ar/gi).length); //2, should be 3
```

[(picture) Example of keypairs on regex101.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jC2B3.png)

As the regex101.com example shows, the ^a overwrites the ac match, so only 2 matches are found. I need to count every instance, even duplicates like "^a" as a substring of "ab". I can solve this without regex, but regex is more elegant.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a positive lookahead with an alternation to check for an `a` at the start of the string and capture the values in capture groups, which you can check for in the code.

```
(?=(a[bcr])|(?<=^(a)))
```

- `(?=` positive lookahead

  - `(a[bcr])` Capture **group 1**, match either `ab` `ac` or `ar`
  - `|` Or
  - `(?<=^(a))` Positive lookbehind, capture a in **group 2**
- `)` Close positive lookahead

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/REXpaF/1)

```js
const regex = /(?=(a[bcr])|(?<=^(a)))/gmi;
const str = `acceptable`;
let res = Array.from(str.matchAll(regex), m => m[2] ? m[2] : m[1]);
console.log(res)
console.log(res.length)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a way to do it within a single regex, where one match is a substring of another and have it return both. I would chain 2 patterns like this:

```
let string = 'acceptable';
let pattern1 = /a(b|c|r)/gi;
let pattern2 = /^a/gi;

let output = string.match(pattern1).length + string.match(pattern2).length;
console.log(output); // returns 3
```